# How to write the result in text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to write the results in the text file. When I am printing the results I can be able to result but when I am moving the result I cannot see in the text file.
Here is the code that I have written

```
with open ('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readline(1)
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        a=len(line)
        b=line.find('The',0,a)
        c=line.find('are',0,a)
        b= b+4
        b1=str(line[b:b+7])
        c=c+4
        c1=str(line[c:c+7])
        var = ' '
        var = "".join([b1, c1])
        var1=str(var)
        print (var)
with open ('new.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(var)
```

result that I am seeing when printing but in the text file. Appending the text is working but I do not want to append the text every time I execute. I just want only once even if I execute n times.

```
eating mango
```

Help me where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try not setting the `file` to `file.write(var)`, and just do `file.write(var)`. you can also try `print(var, file="new.txt")`.

Comment: Are you indenting properly? `line = fp.readline(1)` should be indented under `with open('file.txt'.....)`, and the write at the bottom should be within its `with` statement as well.

Comment: @PYer for print (var, file='new.txt') I am getting like "string object has no attribute write". Still no even after using the first syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call file.write, not just assign it to a variable:

```
with open ('new.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write (var)
```

Could this be what you need:

```
v = ''
with open ('file.txt', 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readline(1)
    while line:
        line = fp.readline()
        a=len(line)
        b=line.find('The',0,a)
        c=line.find('are',0,a)
        b= b+4
        b1=str(line[b:b+7])
        c=c+4
        c1=str(line[c:c+7])
        var = ' '
        var = "".join([b1, c1])
        var1=str(var)
        v+=var+'\n'
with open ('new.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(v)
```

Comment: it still did not work. I cannot see the output in the text file

Comment: Can you post the output when you print var?

Answer (score 0):

think this might be this issue

```
file = file.write (var)
```

you're assigning it to a variable instead of just calling it, should be:

```
file.write(var)
```

also in the future if you plan on outputting several lines of code to a file, look into using the logging module ;) https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: I tried this as well but I still could not be able to see the output. If we want to print multiple lines let's say 2K lines or more even then will file.write works or do I need to go for logging concept?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with two issues with your code.

#### 1) Assigning file to the new file

Don't use the code `file = file.write(var)`. Instead what you would want is: `file.write(var)`

#### 2) File is already a built in

You shouldn't use this variable name, as it is already built in to python. Name the variable `f` or something else.

Here's a working example on repl.it [Writing To A File](https://repl.it/@PYer/MediumpurpleCrimsonQueryoptimizer#main.py).

Please comment if there are any other problems or questions.

Comment: I made a mistake by assigning it to another variable. The point you mentioned I do not think It matters It even after writing file. I figured it Thank you